# jquery validate specific error message placement

Tags: jquery, validation

**ISSUE**: Each of the four required fields has 'Name RequiredCompany RequiredEmail RequiredPhone Required' rather than just the applicable corresponding message.

I have a very compact form and can't use the standard error after input placement of jquery validate. The labels are display:block and there is plenty of room for the error message, so it was decided that's where the error message goes.

so for html like this (wanting the error in span.error_label):

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="company">Company&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="error_label"></span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company">
</div>
```

my jquery looks like:

```
$('#frmContact').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        company: {
            required: true
        },
        phone_number: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    errorLabelContainer: "label",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $(element).append( "<span class='error_label'>" + error + "</span>")
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: 'Name Required'
        },
        company: {
            required: 'Company Required'
        },
        phone_number: {
            required: 'Phone Required'
        },
        email: {
            required:  'Email Required',
            email: 'Please enter a valid email address'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: so what's the question here?

Comment: how do I only show the message for the specific income rather than ALL of the messages for each?

Comment: I'm still lost, http://jsfiddle.net/ag2se9Lg/

Comment: I don't see a code difference from mine to yours but still, this is what I am getting ...http://cl.ly/image/35321p0t2r2y

Comment: that's why I said I'm lost, anyways, try this one, I made some changes in JS and HTML, look for changes and see if this fix the issue http://jsfiddle.net/ag2se9Lg/4/

Comment: any luck with changes?

Comment: last one works perfectly ... thanks

Comment: I asked because I"m using the same code which i suggested you and having problem with it, error triggers but not showing, hahahahahahaha, it's freaking funny

Comment: but my HTML is bit different, I'm using selector `input-groups`, if I put `errors element` inside selector `input-groups` erorr shows but breaks the layout and when I put `errors element` outside the selector `input-groups` error triggers but not show